# Do I need to prefix the input variables for two HTML forms in same page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, attachment

I'm a bit confused of do I need to prefix form input variables with i.e. ('`car_`', or '`bike_`' corresponding to '`car_make`', '`bike_make`') or can I use same template for both forms without prefixing variables. And if so, do I still need to prefix the 'submit' field, or having different form name is enough to avoid data collision.

I have these two HTML forms on the same page:

```
<form action="" name="car_search_form" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="make" value="Audi" />
<input type="submit" name="car_do_search" value="Search Car" />
</form>
<form action="" name="bike_search_form" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="make" value="Schwinn" />
<input type="submit" name="bike_do_search" value="Search Bike" />
</form>
```

So, in the end I want to get correct value for `$validCarMake` via this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['car_do_search']))
{
     $paramCarMake = isset($_POST['make']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['make']) : '';
     $validCarMake = esc_sql($paramCarMake); // For SQL queries only
     // TODO: Add data saving to database
}
```

Also, I want to understand the decision process of PHP engine. How it does deside which variable to choose - how it know on which button I clicked, and why not it does just submit all forms on the page? Also, if there would be any difference if I'd use "GET" method instead of "POST" besides that the one does put the variable values to URL? And how does the GET case it would process attached image to form submit then (as the maximum URL lenght is 255 chars as I know, and i.e. JPEG 100 kiB image contains thousands of chars. I'm asking this, because I also want to allow not just have that search on site's home page, but also allow to make search from a separate website's some kind of widget.

And the last question - if the HTML form processing differs somehow in PHP 7.X compared to PHP 5.X (i.e. PHP 5.4). I means does it caches somewhere the data, does it sends over the internet the attached images of the both forms and consumes network and server data, or it submit's only the data of the form on which I clicked the button.

Comment: in theory, if elements `id` is not used (because need to be unique), you can reuse the same form and names in the same page, because only one form can be submitted at a time (if you don't add custom actions for that in JS of course). However, at reception, if you want to know which form was submitted, you should identify it, with a hidden field for example

Comment: php doesnt care about html. php will fill the $_POST with everything it finds in the body of a POST http request and fill $_GET from query parameters of that request. What you need to understand is how the browser creates http requests.Simply said: if you click a submit button of a <form>, the browser will look for all the inputs of that form and depending on the method/action (mostly GET or POST) will create that http request for you. Maybe this helps. Try looking at the request in the developer tools of your browser

Comment: very broad question, also off topic in the second half. You laid out two scenarios, you can use any one of those really, depends on your requirements or your needs or if it boils down to that, your preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you keep the 2 input requests separate having the post arg "make" is completely fine.  If you send the args in the same request the 2nd will override the first since it was last set.

As for how php decides on what is first it uses what is called order of precedence.  This means what it comes to first it executes first unless explicitly told not to.

Comment: "As for how php decides on what is first it uses what is called order of precedence. This means what it comes to first it executes first unless explicitly told not to." - this is unclear part of the answer. So if there is `var1` on HTML form like 10 and `var1` of same html form line 11, you want to say that the data will be taken from the line 10, not line 11?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to understand the decision process of PHP engine. How it does decide which variable to choose - how it know on which button I clicked, and why not it does just submit all forms on the page?

When you click on a button, php will take the `<button name="value">` value assigned in the name property of the input field or button clicked. This is how it can decide what's the form to submit. Consider that if you have two forms with the same name assigned to the submit button, the first one will override the second and php will only submit one form. This is because php execute operations with a logical order.

Comment: So form name="X" must be different to avoid being overriden by the second form? Does the input type="submit" name has to be different as well then?

Comment: Yes, every name attribute in a form must be unique. As wroted in other comments, php will look for the form method setted, so if you set `<form method="post">` it will make an http post request, this is the best way to handle a form when you need to manage a login form or any other sensitive information. the http get method instead will add a query string to the url, so if you have a form like this `<form method="get">`, in your url you will have the question mark followed by the string that php will process to do the desired operations `?query=param`

Comment: I mean not in the form, but comparing two forms in same page. Are the form name has to be different compared the first form and name. And is the also applies to form input variables, and submit button? By comparing that two forms are in different <form> tags

Comment: Your advice is incorrect.  You can have themsame name and exact same form as long as they are sent independently php does not care what names you use as long as they are valid of course. So you cannot have 2 inputs with the name "BOB" as the second input will override the first.  But if you have 2 forms and both forms have an input of "BOB" that is fine. As only 1 request will be sent at a time.

Comment: @jgetner this is what i mean in the comment. I think it's better to assign unique name to avoid problems.

Comment: I don't disagree with you on that in most cases but there is a time and place where having the same request param's in the case of common functionality is and can be a convenience.  But these days with 2 way data binding its far less common.

Comment: It's a fault of mine, sorry. Usually i don't use the same name param inside a form input, but your clarification is very useful, more than mine.